# How to make a Slider background image slide in another div. (Wordpress Divi theme)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slider

I'm currently working on a website where the designer asked me to make the main slider background image to be sliding in the footer too. I've currently builded up the website with Divi theme in Wordpress with other devs, which integrated the footer in a .js file so it could be seen in every pages. The issue i'm facing is that there are 7 pages in total and every page has it's own slider, and the designer want them to be the same image as the top slider. So i was wondering if there is a way to make that happen.

I'm fairly new to coding (and i got a job, lucky me ) and i didn't had the time to learn JavaScript in details. Hope you guys can help me